# How to click on some image which occurs multiple times on screen with sikuli with java?

Tags: java, testing, automation, sikuli, gui-testing

I am writing some script automation in java which searches some recordings for mobile number and finds multiple recording in gridview. Next to this I am trying to download all recordings by clicking download (multiple)button(s).
I have written below code but does not work

```
public static Screen s = new Screen();
Iterator <Match> matches  =s.findAll("downloadbtn_wh.png"); // s is screen
Pattern pButton = new Pattern("downloadbtn_wh.png");

Match mButton;

while (matches.hasNext()) {
    Match m = matches.next(); // m now could be inspected with debugging
    s.click(m); // click on drop-down

    if ((mButton = s.exists(pButton))!=null) {
        // checks for button image and saves the match
        s.click(mButton); // just click the match, do not search again
        break;
    }
}
```

This script stops after clicking on first download button but I expect that it should click on every download button in gridview. 
[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eODdi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will perform what you require.

```
@Test
public void multiplePattern() throws FindFailed{

    ImagePath.setBundlePath("C:\\patterns\\");

    Screen s = new Screen();
    Iterator<Match> it = s.findAll("downloadArrow.png");

    while(it.hasNext()){

        it.next().highlight(1);
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: Please note that in the above example I am not actually clicking but only highlighting the detected patterns just to visualize the process. Just replace `highlight(1)` with `click()` before you use it in your script.

Comment: Worked!!!!! Thanks Eugene!!!!!! Added click() instead of highlight()  :)

Comment: @Steve Happy to hear that it helped. Please accept my answer.

Comment: @Steve You don't need any reputation to accept an answer. Reputation only required if you want to upvote or downvote a question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Screen scn = new Screen();  
Iterator <Match> itr = scn.findAll("image");
{
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        itr.next().click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just posting some code is not an answer to the question. Please edit your question and add an explanation to your code.